# Many to Many Django Model

Tags: python, django

Hello i am trying to figure out the best way to design this model, this is what i have so far but i am running into issues of having a start and end date per service per customer

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    name     = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False, unique=True)
    services = models.ManyToManyField(Service)
    
class Service(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
```

What would be the best way to design this in order to get the data to look like this:

```
Customer        ||      Services        ||      Start       ||      End
Customer A          Service A               1/1/2001        1/1/2010
                    Service B               2/2/2002        2/2/2011
                    Service C               3/3/2003        3/3/2012
                    
Customer B          Service A               4/4/2004        4/4/2014
                    Service C               5/5/2005        5/5/2015
```

Have been breaking my head for last few days trying to figure out what is the best way to design this model. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: The right way is to have a third table to contain "ServicesRendered", that has references to Customer and Service with the Start and End date.  The "Customer" and "Service" tables don't need to know anything about that.

Comment: How would i do that in django, sorry never had to make a table like that before in django?

Comment: Presumably, `Customer` has only `name`; `Service` has only `name`; and `ServicesRendered` has a `customer` column which is `ForeignKey`, a `service` column which is a `ForeignKey`, and `start` and `end`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an intermediate table.

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False, unique=True)
    
class Service(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    architecture = models.NameField()
    
class customer_services(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='customer_service_entries')
    service = models.ForeignKey(Service, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='customer_service_entries')
    start = models.DateField()
    end = models.DateField()
```

With the related_name args above, you can traverse the foreign key back from the target record using a prop named `customer_service_entries`. A Django template example with `customers` passed as a list of `Customer` instances:

```
{% for customer in customers %}
    <p> Customer is {{ customer }}</p>
    <ul> Services:
        {% for entry in customer.customer_service_entries.all %}
            <li>{{ entry.service }} (architecture:{{ entry.service.architecture|default_if_none:"None" }})</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Wouldn't the m2m be irrelevant? In this instance services are just types of services a customer can have and they are universal to all customers. You get the same data by querying the `services` field from the `customer_services` model when you are searching a specific customer. Can you please explain what I might be missing?

Comment: @ViaTech Good eye, updated

Comment: perfect, thank you so much exactly what i was looking for. Just had a quick question, how do i reference another field in the service table, while querying the customer_services table, like for instance, if i had another field in the service table called lets say "architecture" and i wanted to print that field in a template how would i reference it?

Comment: Gave an (untested) example above. See Django docs for `related_name`- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name

Comment: That was an awesome idea, but i just tried that, and can;t get it to work, i read the documentation, but still can't figure out how to get it to work